# What name should be given to this allophone of /tʃ/?

Tags: english, phonetics, phones, allophones, idiolect

I am a native English speaker, but when I make the sound which should be /tʃ/, I have been told that I begin it by placing the tip of my tongue briefly between my teeth, as if I was going to start a dental fricative. It strikes me that this is somewhat unusual – the tip of the tongue should start behind the front teeth, no?

Is there a more accurate way of describing the sound I am producing? i.e. is it still a voiceless palato-alveolar affricate?

(Having read [this on English Langage Learners SE](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/17245/how-to-pronounce-ch-j-sounds) I think I may be producing a sound closer to [t͡ɕ] [voiceless alveolo-palatal affricate], although my anglophone-ears struggle to distinguish these two.)

Comment: Sounds as if the _alveolar_ part is being replaced by a _dental_. Voiceless dental-palatal affricate.

Comment: Yes, but is that a real thing? You're right...but I can't find any reference such a phoneme.

Comment: I think (from doing more reading) that this is just an example of an inefficiency in the way I must have learnt to articulate the [tʃ] sound.

Comment: Well it isn't an English phoneme but it's still a sound.

Comment: quite right..should say sound

Comment: @curiousdannii A non-phoneme, or an idiolectal allophone of a phoneme?

Comment: @StoneyB Ah, I think that's the term: _idiolectal allophone_. Just my own strange way of trying to say [tʃ]. I can produce the proper [tʃ] sound with concious effort. For some reason I briefly place the tip of my tongue between my teeth when I'm saying it without thinking.

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing it by touching your teeth, you're more likely pronouncing (if I'm reading correctly) either /tθ/ (voiceless **dental** affricate) or /t̪ɕ/ (voiceless **denti-alveopalatal** affricate). A voiceless **postalveolar** affricate would rather be /tʃ/. I'm not actually sure of the exact sound you're making as I can't hear you, but this is my best guess.